# RStudio- How to produce inline r results?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

For example, I want to be able to do "The result is ...." and have the ... be replaced with the r output. I considered using "cat", but it is not as neat.

Here is another example of what I wish to achieve.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 2)
a<- mean(x)
```
````

The result of running a random number generator from a normal distribution with mean 0 and sd 2 has a mean of (somehow output variable a).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks with a leading `r`, for instance:

```
2 + 2 = `r 2+2`.
```

or in your case,

```
the result is `r a`
```